How can I deploy SSR React Application on Vercel?
I have a react application where I am using vercel serverless apis to send emails and text messages. I want to server side render my application mainly for SEO. Previously, I've managed SSR by keeping my server code in the same repository but in a separate folder, deploying via Jenkins. I'm unsure how to handle this setup on Vercel and maintain a smooth deployment process.
Please do not suggest to use Nextjs.
